# Repeated background image is stretched

Tags: android, background, repeat, tile, stretch

I'm having quite a hard time with a textured background. I have a 60px by 60px bitmap texture that I want to set as the background for my layout in a repeated tile pattern. Here's the layout xml located in res/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_texture_background" >

    ...
</RelativeLayout
```

And here is the dark_texture_background, located in res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/dark_background_texture"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

The dark_background_texture is the 60x60 pixel image.

So, the issue is that the texture image is being enlarged while also being tiled. I added a red line to the outside of the texture image to see exactly where the texture images were, and here's the result:

[image: Tiled Background]

I also added the screen height, width and density according to getResources().getDisplayMetrics().

Since the screen width is 480 pixels, the texture image should be repeated 8 times across (480 / 60 = 8). Instead, there are only 5 ~1/4. The image is now ~90 pixels and tiled. WTF?

Why is my texture image being stretched when I explicitly tell it to repeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what Raghav's referring to with the bug, exactly, but if they've changed something in ICS+ then there was certainly *something* wrong. That said, I'm fairly certain that bitmap images in `drawable` are assumed to be `mdpi`, and scaled from there (maybe they changed that behavior?), which makes sense given that your 60px image became 90px (60 * 1.5 scaling factor).

You can avoid scaling altogether, keeping in mind that the physical size will differ on different densities (although for a tiled background it's probably not important), by placing your bitmaps into a `drawable-nodpi` folder only. Android will use those drawables without scaling, regardless of density.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in the Android framework, that was fixed ICS onwards. Anyhow, here's the rough workaround for pre ICS versions:

```
public static void fixBackgroundRepeat(View view) {
    Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
    if (bg != null) {
        if (bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bmp = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
            bmp.mutate(); // make sure that we aren't sharing state anymore
            bmp.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
        }
    }
}
```

Apply it to all Views that have a tiled background set (i.e. findViewById() them).

Sometimes, the bug starts acting up after setting `anyDensity=true` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug? I would think it's because it's doing density scaling. @Chewie can you try placing your image in `drawable-nodpi` and see if that works?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I remember reading a mail from either Romain or Dianne on the android-developers Google group that said so.

Comment: @kcoppock this was it! Apparently I missed the whole thing about images in /drawable will be pre-scaled on the assumption that they are at mdpi size. I'll toss a correct answer your way if you submit it.

Comment: Yes this is bug!! I used nodpi folder but it doesn't solved the scaled image.. this function "fixBackgroundRepeat" solved that,, thanks alot Raghav Sood